# How using HttpTestingController can I flush with a header?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, http-headers

I've got a Angular service that calls a http api, this API returns a file blob.   The service passes the response to a file save method to present the file for downloading.

I'm struggling with the unit testing of this method, specifically making sure there is a response with the right headers in it.
I think its part of the TestRequest.flush() function

```
flush(body: ArrayBuffer | Blob | string | number | Object | (string | number | Object | null)[] | null, opts: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [name: string]: string | string[];
    };
    status?: number;
    statusText?: string;
} = {}): void
```

But I can' t workout how to add headers.

```
        req.flush(file, {
        headers: {
            [name: 'Content-Disposition']= '' },
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK'
    });
```

Comment: You're confusing *types* and *values*; `{'Content-Disposition': ''}` is the appropriate value, because the `headers` property accepts an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep having real trouble understanding the help tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doh, can't decode the help definition of the function:

Its simpler and this works:

```
req.flush(file, {
            headers: { 'Content-Disposition': 'part1;part2' },
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK'
        });
```